# How to rotate a rectangle in 3d space using an axis as a HINGE?

Tags: algorithm, 3d, geometry, graphics2d, rotation

I'm looking forward mathematical or algorithmic calculation of rotating a rectangle with a fixed axis as a HINGE. As you can see in the below picture.

> I have positions (x,y) of 4 points of rectangle vertices, and the origin is center of the rectangle,  so the desired algorithm will project my original shape's vertices into the desire shape vertices. (Please see image below)

I  know it's  easy to do it with 3d libraries but i need to do it with 2d graphics in a high-level programming language like .Net or  JAVA or something without any 3d or complementary library.

**Please help me with any idea or reference or better than all a source code or algorithm.**

[image]

Thanks in advance for you quality time.

Comment: Any library that supports rotating will probably support the concept of rotating around different axes.  So, you'll need to be more specific.  Choose a platform for your project, write some code until you get to the point where you need help with rotation, then share your code with us and tell us exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: Thx @mbeckish but my question is general, it's  not about a programming language it's more bout the geometrical calculation or matrix projection of my original 4 vertices to the desired shape's vertices

Comment: If you're just looking for the math behind the rotation transform, and not the method calls of a specific library, then check out Wikipedia.  For example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: After you check out the rotation transform, which will give you the 3D coordinates of your 4 vertices, then check out 3D projection, which will map your 3D coordinates to a 2D plane, since you are doing 2D graphics: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection

Comment: Finally, you may want to implement the concept of a viewing frustum: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum.  3D projection will map every vertex in your 3D model to an infinite 2D plane, most of which is outside of the bounds of your screen.  A viewing frustum defines how a finite region of your 3D model maps to the region of the 2D plane that corresponds to your screen.

Comment: Thanks again,  after searching around and thinking more my problem is more looks like  the all  the axises are fixed and all i have to do is to change the view (the camera) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix but not sure if it's  my solution

Comment: Thanks your View_frustum was my answer, thanks in advance, i answered my question by referencing to your comments.  Thanks again

Comment: @mbeckish - given the answer the OP posted do you want to write this up as a proper answer rather than just comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summarizing my comments above:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, when working with two dimensions, I have found immense success with a wonderful tool called [processing](http://processing.org/).  Processing is an extension of the Java programming language, targeted specifically at the visualization of anything, ranging from data structures to intimidating physics simulations.  From the helpful graphics you presented, I am assuming you want to rotate one structure around a point or axis at any given time. Take a look at the feature rich API reference, processing offers (I am a new user, unfortunately I can not link more than two items, will put link to API reference below).  They have unique functions for rotating and transforming around points.  However, it does not rotate the structure around said point, but rather, rotates the entire screen and everything it contains around the point. For example, if you wanted to rotate everything around the origin (0,0) by 45 degrees, it would be as simple as:

```
void setup()
{
  size(200, 200); // Set the size of the screen to 200 x 200 pixels
  background(255); // Set the background to white
  smooth(); // Smooth the edges of the rectangles
  fill(192); // Fill the rectangle with a light gray
  noStroke(); // No black border on rectangle
  rect(40, 40, 40, 40); // Create an equilateral rectangle (square) that is 40 x 40 pixels at the point (40,40)

  pushMatrix(); //Let the compiler know that you will be modifying the Matrix
  rotate(radians(45)); // Rotate the screen about the origin (by default) 45 degrees clockwise
  fill(0); // Color the following rectangle black
  rect(40, 40, 40, 40); // Draw an equivalent rectangle as the last one, only at the new modified screen coordinates
  popMatrix(); // Let the compiler know you are done modifying the matrix
}
```

The above code will create two identical squares, one at the point (40,40) and one at 45 degrees about the origin clockwise.

There is a really detailed tutorial out there that can be found [here](http://processing.org/learning/transform2d/) which explains everything in much greater detail.
I really hope this helps.
All the best!
API Reference: processing.org/reference/

Comment: Thanks @James  for your kind a long response, that library  was really amazing sure i will use it in my project, but  unfortunately as i told you it's i need to do it without any library, in the other words i kinda have to implement some small parts of that library myself so it looks that what mbeckish said is a correct answer to my question. Again thanks for  your sharing