# 3d with gdi - projection algorithm

Tags: c#, c, c#-4.0, math, graphics

i still have the problem to bring 3d data to 2d. i have an array with polygons. every polygon has 3 vertex points with logically 3 values (x,y,z). now i want to draw these polygons with gdi+ which is only 2d. i want to do something like: for every polygon get every vertex point get correct x and y value for this point in all articles i found, is a value which stands for the position of the viewer or the point of view. how can i get this value. it has to be in the center of my window, where i´m painting with gdi+. thanks for help

Comment: Check out my answer to a similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10778210/21727

Comment: I think this old [article on texture mapping from PCGPE](http://www.gamers.org/dEngine/rsc/pcgpe-1.0/texture.txt) may help with 3d->2d projection. That's where I learned it from years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other way (nor that I'm aware of) then

- define a `Plane`, where your **2D** will be drawn
- move your **3D** vertex *along plane normal* versus normal, constrcuting in this way vector/line.
- find intersection of the `Plane` and vector == that would the point you are going to draw in **2D** space.

To define a plane, you can use your 3D engine. It usually achieved (also because it's mathematically correct), by specifying `a point` and `a normal vector`. Having these 2 informations you're able to construct (also mentally) *a plane surface*.